# UiNanigation Bar With background image and rightbarbutton item

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationbar

i have added back ground image to UINavigationBar in drawrect method,image added properly.and also i added right bar button item to Navigation bar in View did load method.
**my problem is i navigate to detail view and when i am coming back to rootview controller, right bar button item is not visible but button action working on navigation bar right side
Can Any one help to solve this**

Comment: Note that overriding -drawRect will not work in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the background image. Apple engineers told me not to do this very thing. I would use the customise options in ios5 instead.